# Align text in center in combo box added into table cell

Tags: java, javafx

Code for editing table column is as below

```
@FXML
private TableView<StateTransition> stateTransitionTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn<StateTransition, Long> stId;
@FXML
private TableColumn<StateTransition, String> stState;
@FXML
private TableColumn<StateTransition, String> stNewState;

private void setTableEditable(Boolean val){

ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(workFlowSet);
stState.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(new DefaultStringConverter(), list));

}
```

This code is giving combo box in table cell but text in combo box is in left side, I want text in center of that ComboBoxTableCell.

Stuck here, help me with that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS. If you add a stylesheet to the `Scene` have the following in the file:

```
.table-column .combo-box .list-cell {
    -fx-alignment: center;
}
```

The `.list-cell` is the important part (for non-editable `ComboBox`), I just put `.table-column` and `.combo-box` so not every `ListCell` on the scene-graph is aligned to the center.

Have a look at the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) for more CSS information.

Comment: Yeah, CSS was the last option and I used it, but same here too, **-fx-alignment** is not working, Don't know why, So as of now I am using **-fx-padding** as an alternate. If you be able to explain it then please explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
stState.setCellFactory(tableCol -> {
            ComboBoxTableCell<StateTransition, String> comboBoxTableCell = new ComboBoxTableCell<>(new DefaultStringConverter(), list);
           comboBoxTableCell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
           return comboBoxTableCell;
        });
```

**Update:**
Try it this way:

```
stState.setCellFactory(col -> {

            return new TableCell<StateTransition, String>() {

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (item == null || empty) {
                        setText(null);

                    }
                    else{
                        ComboBox<String> cb = new ComboBox<>(list);
                        cb.setValue(item);
                        cb.setConverter(new DefaultStringConverter());
                        cb.setStyle("-fx-padding:0.25 0 0.25 3.0");
                        setGraphic(cb);

                    }
                }

            };

        });
```

Comment: unfortunately, Its not working.  Could you please tell me how to add padding into this, or any other way, I tried  as **comboBoxTableCell.setPadding(new Insets(0.25, 0, 0.25, 3.0))** , but failed.